# How can I recalculate a variable upon on screen size?

Tags: java, java-8, minecraft

So, I have 2 variables: `this.width` and `this.height`, that I pass into a class called `GuiElement`, like shown (this is a simplified example):

```java
int w = this.width / 5;
int aspectRatio = 2;
GuiElement guiElement = new GuiElement(w, w * aspectRatio);
```

This would work initially, but when the screen is resized, the `GuiElement` would not change size.

I want to be able to recalculate the width and height upon `this.width` or `this.height` changing (window resize).

Things i’ve already tried/considered:

Getters:

- Would not work due to me having to write loads of getters depending on how many GuiElements I have, I could make a function to calculate screen size depending on parameters, but I would rather not (in order to keep my ui framework as straightforward as possible and to give the user as much customisability as possible)

Passing in the variables everytime the screen is drawn:

- I have considered this, but it would clutter everything up and not work with my current design.

Im using Java 8 btw (Minecraft tag because I’m using mixins to mod minecraft)

And please please don’t tell me to use getters. I’ve considered it many times and have come to the conclusion that it will not work for what i’m doing.

Comment: Im not used to minecraft, but it strikes me odd that you create a new `GuiElement` for every resize. Wouldn't it make more sense to change the size of the existing element instead, e.g. by using a setter (something like setWidth())?

Comment: You could easily make a method resize(width, height) within your GuiElement class rather than making a getter and setter for each variable. Then you would simply call guiElement.resize(newwidth, newheight).

Comment: I have already considered both of your suggestions: 1-Resizing it every time is not something I want to do (makes it easier for the end user), 2- I’m not creating a gui element for every resize (when did i say that), i’m creating the gui elements in the constructor and just want to recalculate the width and height for the function every time the width/height is changed